# When should I use a menu bar icon on macOS?

Tags: menu, human-interface-guideline, mac-os-x, contextual-menu

When writing a desktop application for macOS, in which cases it is useful or advisable to add a menu bar icon? Are there any UI guidelines? And what should happen with the dock icon?

Example Evernote:

[image: Evernote screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below MacOS X Human Interface Guidelines.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/MenuAppearanceBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH23-SW1

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too earlier, specifically 'Menu Bar Extras' is what I was looking for, but it didn't give the right guidance when to use it. For example Evernote or Droplr use it and show a useful popover (though this guideline says not to use popovers), [here screenshot](http://d.pr/i/Dtz8). Other apps use it to show a status (such as whatsapp desktop apps). Then there are some, which popup something similar as spotlight. I would like to know more about these kind of menubar icon usages.

Answer (score 0):

See the "Menu Bar Extras" section of the "Human Interface Guidelines
macOS" documentation [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/menu-bar-extras/)

Comment: Could you copy and paste the relevant information into your answer?